# SAS-Create Dynamic Tables Based On ID With Only Top 3 Showing

Tags: sas

Hi I would really like to create dynamic tables based on the following sample data, create 4 new data sets based upon PAYEE_ID: 522,622,743,and 888.  I want all all of the fields to be in the new 4 data sets, but only have the top 3 AMT_BILLED in the 4 tables for each type of PAYEE_ID

```
PAYEE_ID    PAYEENAME   MSG_CODE    MSG_DESCRIPTION AMT_BILLED  percentbilled   claimscounts    PercentLines    TotalAmount TotNumofClaims
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    AA  text field 1    10000   4%  50  16% 275000  305
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    BB  text field 2    20000   7%  40  13% 275000  305
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    6N  text field 3    30000   11% 30  10% 275000  305
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    5U  text field 4    25000   9%  20  7%  275000  305
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    1F  text field 5    90000   33% 100 33% 275000  305
522 MakeBelieve Center 1    2E  text field 6    100000  36% 65  21% 275000  305
622 Invisible Center 2  A4  text field 1    600 2%  9   7%  34300   134
622 Invisible Center 2  D2  text field 2    700 2%  31  23% 34300   134
622 Invisible Center 2  D4  text field 3    8000    23% 11  8%  34300   134
622 Invisible Center 2  DS  text field 4    10000   29% 62  46% 34300   134
622 Invisible Center 2  F8  text field 5    15000   44% 21  16% 34300   134
743 Pretend Center 1    1K  text field 1    440 1%  2   1%  41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    1N  text field 2    3000    7%  7   3%  41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    1V  text field 3    400 1%  4   2%  41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    2W  text field 4    15000   37% 63  26% 41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    3B  text field 5    500 1%  2   1%  41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    3H  text field 6    7700    19% 41  17% 41040   246
743 Pretend Center 1    3Z  text field 7    14000   34% 127 52% 41040   246
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  B7  text field 1    68000   38% 257 29% 178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  B8  text field 2    5000    3%  47  5%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  B9  text field 3    200 0%  138 16% 178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  BB  text field 4    1562    1%  18  2%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  BO  text field 5    39999   22% 3   0%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  BZ  text field 6    40000   22% 2   0%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  C2  text field 7    500 0%  5   1%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  C5  text field 8    7865    4%  395 45% 178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  C7  text field 9    8649    5%  14  2%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  CR  text field 10   5674    3%  1   0%  178449  886
888 It's A MakeBelieve One  CX  text field 11   1000    1%  6   1%  178449  886
```

to

I'm new to SAS, and this would really help me out.  Thank you so much!

Comment: check sas user guide.

Comment: when you're checking the SAS user guide, maybe start by looking at PROC SORT and the `obs` dataset option.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sort data=sampleData out=sampleData_s;
    by payee_id amt_billed;
run;
```

You can use descending if by 'top' you mean largest e.g. `by payee_id descending amt_billed;`

Once the data are sorted you are able to read into a data step and use `first` and `last` e.g.

```
data partial_solution(drop=count);
    retain count 0;
    set sampleData_s;
    by payee_id descending amt_billed;
    if first.payee_id then count=0;
    count+1;
    if count le 3 then output;
run;
```

To output to different dataset names:

```
proc sort data=sampleData(keep=payee_id) out=all_payee_ids nodupkey;
    by payee_id;
run;

data _null_;
    length id_list $10000;   * needs to be long enough to contain all ids;
                             * if you do not state this, sas will default; 
                             * length to first value;
    retain id_list;
    set all_payee_ids end=eof;
    id_list = catx('|', id_list, payee_id);
    if eof then call symputx('macroVarIdList', id_list);
run;
```

You've now got a pipe separated list of all your id's. You can loop through these using them to create names for you datasets. You need to do this as SAS needs to know the names of the datasets you want to output to up front e.g.

```
data ds1 ds2 ds3 ds4;
    set some_guff;
    if blah then output ds1;
    else if blahblah then output ds2;
    else output d3;
    output d4;
run;
```

So with the macro var loop:

```
%let nrVars=%sysfunc(countw(&macroVarIdList));

data
    %do i = 1 %to &nrVars;
        dataset_%scan(&macroVarIdList,&i,|)
    %end;
    ;
    set partial_solution;
    count+1;
    %do j = 1 %to &nrVars;
        %let thisPayeeId=%scan(&macroVarIdList,&j,|);
        if payee_id = "&thisPayeeId" then output dataset_&thisPayeeId.;
    %end;
run;
```